# What's the best way to override a user's .vnc xstartup?

Tags: x11, vnc

I want to be able to override a user's `.vnc/xstartup` behavior as a sysadmin option.

My users are fairly cooperative, so I'm about to add this to the beginning of the `.vnc/xstartup` file in `/etc/skel`:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -x /etc/SPECIALDIR/$USER ]; then
    exec /etc/SPECIALDIR/$USER
fi
...
```

But now I'm thinking, "is there a better way to do this?".  My `$vncStartup` in `/etc/vnc.conf` points to `/etc/X11/Xsession`, so maybe there's some way to override how this works.

**Update**

Looks like `.vnc/xstartup` overrides the setting in `/etc/vnc.conf`

Comment: `.vnc/xstartup` appears in the man page for tigervncserver: